# Does MySQL's REGEXP operator support searching by character code?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unicode

Let's say I'm writing a SQL statement and I want to find all the rows that have strange characters in them. Is there a way to do this with MySQL?

```
SELECT foo, bar, beep, bop
FROM widgets
WHERE widget_name REGEXP '???'
```

The Perl equivalent would be something like

```
/\x{FFF}/ # character ordinal 4095, unused tibetan character
```

Comment: What are "*strange characters*"?  You could just place the characters for which you wish to search directly into the regular expression.

Comment: What is the brief, canonical way of saying "characters whose ordinal is higher than 127 or 255"?

Comment: By "*ordinal*", do you mean the integer value of the character's binary encoding?  Or the codepoint?  In either case, under what encoding?

Comment: Yes, are they not the same thing? Does it matter the encoding? Wouldn't it be position N in the field's encoding?

Comment: For example, [CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/415/) has codepoint `0x0415` (decimal 1,045) in Unicode, but binary encoding `0xd095` (decimal 53,397) in UTF-8.  The same character has both codepoint and binary encoding `0x85` (decimal 133) in x-MacCyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find strings that cannot be represented in some particular encoding, e.g. Windows-1252, you could convert the string to that encoding and compare against itself:

```
WHERE CONVERT(widget_name USING latin1) != widget_name
```